# Преобразование char в float через байты с++

Tags: c++, память, char, float, преобразование-типов

У меня есть массив **char**, его размер кратен 4. Мне нужно составить из этих четырех символов **float**, используя байты **char**-значений.

Пример: есть число *57.424999237060546875*. с++ использует стандарт IEEE-754 (как я смог найти). Переводим это число в двоичный вид согласно стандарту - получаем: 01000010 01100101 10110011 00110011. Создаем массив **char**:

`char ch[4] = { char(0b01000010), char(0b01100101), char(0b10110011), char(0b00110011) };`

Далее нужно получить `float x;` , в котором будет храниться непосредственно *57.424999237060546875*.

Первый вариант: `::memcpy(&x, ch, sizeof(float));`

Второй вариант: `x = *(float *)&ch;`

Оба варианта выводят число *8.35376e-08*. Получается, они вроде как делают одно и то же, и скорее всего правильно в пределах того, что я говорю им делать, но я говорю им делать не то, что требуется мне. То есть, где то происходит изменение битов, которое я не могу понять, или **float** строится как-то по другому.

Как правильно преобразовать массив **char** в **float**-значение?

Полный код:

```
int main()
{
    char ch[4] = { char(0b01000010), char(0b01100101), char(0b10110011), char(0b00110011) };
    float x;
    ::memcpy(&x, ch, sizeof(float));
    cout << x << endl;
    x = *(float *)&ch;
    cout << x << endl;
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

**UPD:** инициализировал значения массива через 0x, но при изменении на 0b ошибка та же.

Comment: Стандартного способа нет. Можно учесть порядок байт при помощи макросов, как тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991478/building-a-32-bit-float-out-of-its-4-composite-bytes , специфичные случаи обычно учитываются только для конкретных целевых архитектур. Можно еще погуглить библиотеки на эту тему, но тут я ничего не подскажу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обратите порядок char

```
char ch[4] = { char(0b00110011), char(0b10110011), char(0b01100101), char(0b01000010) };
```

`>>57.425`

[Хранение вещественных чисел может зависеть от порядка байт; так, на x86 используются форматы IEEE 754 со знаком и порядком числа в старших байтах.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)